# Two-Way Routing Service

Tags: wcf, wcf-routing

I have the following requirement:

Client can call the router/relay service, which in turn calls a service on the target server. The target server sends back a result to the relay service which will forward it back to the client.

I've looked at [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/368463/how-to-design-and-implement-a-simple-wcf-service-relay) but I do not think it would suffice my needs because *I assume* this is only a one-way message from the client, to the relay service and finally to the target server.

I'm fairly new to WCF so I would like to get some insight about this issue so I would focus my research in the right direction.

Comment: This looks like standard WCF request / reply router so where is the problem? Did you check [WCF Routing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee517421.aspx)?

Comment: @Ladislav Mrnka: so do you think the implementation of the relay service I've linked to is what I'm actually looking for? I'm not sure my assumptions are right... and this is why I'm asking in the first place (so I would know what to research for)

Comment: The link you mentioned is old, WCF Routing is newer way with build in support but generally yes you can write router / relay yourselves.

Comment: @Ladislav Mrnka: One more question please... Do I need to look into Duplex Router or is that beyond the scope of my problem?

Comment: Duplex is for scenarios where server can call the client independently on request - for example client calls the server to initiate connection and than server calls the client back multiple times. If you expect traditional request response pattern you don't need duplex router.