# URL Rewrite for WCF

Tags: c#, wcf, iis, url-rewriting, hosting

I am in a scenario to rewrite all the requests from WCF to another, i have achieved that with  the help of below.

```
<httpRedirect enabled="false" destination="" />
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="ReverseProxyInboundRule1" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="(.*)" />
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="http://localhost:8888/{R:1}" />
                    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny">
                    </conditions>
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
```

this is redirecting all my requests from http://localhost:7777/ to http://localhost:8888/

I have to achieve this based on parameter (Rule) for WCF.

**Service 1:**

```
public string GetData(List<String> value)
        {
            return string.Format("You entered: {0}", value[0]);
        }
```

i just want to write a rule like, **if value is not null & first value from the list is "test"** then the request has to be redirected to the second service(**http://localhost:8888/**) along with the parameter. How do i write a rule for this..,

Comment: WCF using WebHttpBinding doesn’t support array as parameter, it couldn’t have been the query string. if we use the SOAP WCF service, the parameter will be stored in the soap message along with Http Post request. So we could not get the content of the request body (so far as I know).

Comment: Build a relay service that sits behind your original endpoint and then in your relay service handle the content based routing: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/368463/how-to-design-and-implement-a-simple-wcf-service-relay